# Exception handling inconsistency when using Hostfxr to call a callback method in a try catch on ubuntu

Tags: c++, .net-core, coreclr

Im playing around with the hostfxr sample and got it working a bit but im running into an issue when using exceptions n c++

The setup I have now is that the NativeHost.cpp has a method that throws an error  named ErrorHandler. This method is passed in a try catch to c# and is called there. Now Im expecting that the catch for std::invalid_argument will be entered when the error is thrown in the ErrorHandler method. Now for windows this works, but on my Ubuntu VM it just aborts and throws the invalid_argument. Where am I going wrong on this?

Simplified Sample(Full repro https://github.com/gertkommer/HostFxr-exception-issue)

```
//NativeHost.cpp
static void ErrorHandler(){
    throw std::invalid_argument("TEST");
}

int main(){
    //TAKEN OUT - Load netcore stuff and functionptr to c# function InvokeCallBack
    try{
        InvokeCallBack(ErrorHandler)
    }catch(std::invalid_argument e){
        std::cout << "This is a test to see if i get in the catch";
    }
}

//Lib.cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public delegate void ErrorHandler();

public delegate void InvokeCallBackDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ErrorHandler function);
public static void InvokeCallBack([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ErrorHandler function)
{
   function();//Call ErrorHandler here
}
```

**Expected output**
On both windows and ubuntu
`This is a test to see if i get in the catch`

**Actual output**
Windows
`This is a test to see if i get in the catch`
Ubuntu 20.04
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'`
  `what():  TEST`

Comment: In my experience it is never a good idea to let exceptions cross technology boundaries. So any C++ exceptions must be caught and handled before you reach the managed domain of .Net and the other way around.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Hey Pepijn, I now just have a error structure that I marshal and when I'm done with the InvokeCallback then I check in the c++ if the structure is filled by the c#. That seems to be the best solution for now. Thanks for your comment and merry Christmas :)

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me. And good to hear you could make a step . Best wishes to you too